# Why does my nserver fail on uptime.com checking?

Tags: dns-hosting, cloudflare

I've just tried my site via [uptime.com](http://uptime.com) and get the following: [image: following]

My site is hosted on my own server, but through CloudFlare. What should I do to resolve the error? What am I missing, and what does it mean to fail this kind of test?

**UPDATE:** The site I'm checking for is [upwork.com](https://uptime.com/upwork.com)

Comment: Post your domain name if you want help. This question will be closed as either being too vague or not having a desired outcome, so you may want to edit it to be more complete and clear. Suggest you post the CloudFlare DNS screen screenshot as well. Basically you put your CloudFlare DNS server names into the place you registered your domain.

Comment: @Tim I've updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website works fine. When you identify a problem with how your website works please clearly state what the problem is. A vague error report by a testing service is not a problem, it could be a bug with the test.

I do note that one name server has a weird error, reported by [MXToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3Aupwork.com&run=toolpage#).

```
SOA Serial Number Format is Invalid
fay.ns.cloudflare.com reported Serial 2022417197 : Serial year was 2022 which is in the future.
```

Again though, if the website and email work, there's probably no problem.